# Rails and association in to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an association one to many from foo and bar.

i do a foo.to_json(:include => :bar) but i want to display not all the rows of bar, but only the last, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but in case you're still looking for an answer...

You'll probably have to build the JSON hash yourself, like so:

```
{
  'foo' => {
    'title': foo.title,
    ...,
    'bars' => [foo.bars.last.attributes]
  }
}
```

or if you don't want to list each attribute,

```
{
  'foo' => {
    'bars' => [foo.bars.last.attributes]
  }.merge(foo.attributes)
}
```

Hope that helps!